# What airport has this walkway over a taxiway?

Tags: airport

I saw this image posted in [another question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/15463/65). **What airport is this?**

[image: 747 being marshaled beneath a passenger bridge]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This image was taken at [London Gatwick](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/travelnews/2585628/Passengers-warned-BAA-break-up-will-not-lead-to-fare-cuts.html). The bridge connects two portions of the North Terminal, right next to where the North Terminal is labeled on this map:

[image: Map of London Gatwick Airport]

London Gatwick [claims to be the first airport](http://www.gatwickairport.com/business-community/about-gatwick/at-a-glance/history/) to have such a feature. As can be seen in the photo, it is [the largest in the world](http://www.airport-technology.com/projects/pier6/), high enough for a 747 to pass underneath.

This is not the only airport to have such a feature, though. [Denver International](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denver_International_Airport) also has a [bridge (picture)](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/DEN-_PED_BRIDGE.JPG) over the taxiway connecting the terminal building with Concourse A. This one is not as high as the bridge at Gatwick and can't clear anything larger than a 737.

Comment: Thanks, fooot! I got busy wandering around London area airports on Google maps, and forgot to come back to give you an upvote...

Comment: I tried a [TinEye](http://TinEye.com) search, but all it came up with was the imgur link of the original post

Comment: @FreeMan Interesting, I used Google and it identified Gatwick (and found the article I linked to).

Comment: You can see it in this [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Gatwick+Airport/@51.1573564,-0.1826259,365a,20y,90h,41.63t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x59dda4bf018973ff!6m1!1e1) image -- they even took the photo just as a plane was going under the bridge.

Comment: KLIA2 in Kuala Lumpur also has sky bridge